# How can I generate string from a database specific column values with some condition and each column value separate into comma(,)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm send string data into server side which contains multiple int/double values and I separate this string values to find comma(,) and convert it into double type. I do this well. But when I retrieve this values and show this like as when I insert this value.
[image]

```
IQueryable<JSISetup> jsiQuery = jsiSetupRepository.AsQueryable();
```

I retrieve this all value but I can't proper condition to do this.

[image]

Comment: Could you expand on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Do I understand now?

Comment: Not really.. could you post more code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use SQL `STUFF` to generate a string with comma-separated

```
SELECT jsid,  amount = STUFF(
         (SELECT ',' + convert(varchar,Amount )
          FROM test t1
          WHERE t1.jsid = t2.jsid
          FOR XML PATH (''))
         , 1, 1, '') from test t2
group by jsid;
```

Comment: Please help me to solve this  using entity framework.